# how do I get ipython to raise warnings everytime (repeated warnings) ?

Tags: warnings, ipython

I would like to import a module, use a function of that module and get a warning message every time the event that triggers the warning happens, not just the first time.

For example if I do (within ipython):

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = sp.linspace(0,10)
plt.plot(x,1j*x)
```

I get the following warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py:320: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

however, if I do

```
plt.plot(x,1j*x)
```

again, I don't get a warning message. As I said above, I would like to receive a warning message every time, not just the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Add

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('always')
```

before calling

```
plt.plot(x, 1j*x)
```